# Library to create self querying SNMP Agent in Java

Tags: java, snmp, self-reference

I am trying to create an SNMP Management Agent that will query itself the OID of the Object to be retrieved. It will retrieve the value and store it in an internal database for later retrieval. The system will be coded in Java and deployed in Linux 14.04 LTS.

So, I wanted to know if there are any Java libraries that can efficiently carry out this task of self querying and object retrieval. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "self query"? A SNMP agent connects to a port and queries it, it does not care who provides this service or who is behind it.

Comment: sorry the question might not have been that clear. By 'Management Agent' I mean the software running in the managed machine. Not the software outside the machine ('Management Station') that connects to query from it. I want the application running in the machine to retrieve data from the MIB, format it and store it in a separate database

Answer (score 0):

Both agents and managers can be implemented with http://www.snmp4j.org/